Add 2 columns from different tables in Power BI table visual
I want to add the following 2 columns in Power BI table visual.
Now these 2 columns are fetched after alot of filters and from 2 different tables
SS of the columns
I have tried using the modeling tab but it is adding a column in 1 of the tables which is not something I want
